# Performing rolling average on streaming data from Kafka using PySpark and without using window

Tags: apache-kafka, pyspark

I have been trying to perform data aggregation on streaming data, getting the following error:

> Window approach has this issue - 'Non-time-based windows are not supported on streaming DataFrames/Datasets'

I am looking for an alternative method to the window approach to perform aggregation on streaming data.

```
    w = (Window
     .partitionBy("orig_time")
     .orderBy(F.col("epoch").cast('long'))
     .rangeBetween(-minutes(5), 0))
#windowedDeviceDF = deviceDF.withColumn('rolling_average', F.avg("tag_value").over(w))
windowSpec5 = Window.partitionBy("orig_time").orderBy(F.col("epoch").cast('long')).rangeBetween(-minutes(5),0)
windowSpec10 = Window.partitionBy("orig_time").orderBy(F.col("epoch").cast('long')).rangeBetween(-minutes(10), 0)

windowedDeviceDF = deviceDF.withColumn("avg5", F.avg("tag_value").over(windowSpec5)).withColumn("avg10",F.avg("tag_value").over(windowSpec10)).withColumn('occurrences_in_5_min', F.count('epoch').over(w)).withColumn('rolling_average', F.avg("tag_value").over(w)).select(
"tag_name", "epoch", "avg5", "avg10", "occurrences_in_5_min", "rolling_average")

windowedDeviceDF = deviceDF.groupBy(deviceDF.tag_name, deviceDF.tag_value, window(deviceDF.orig_time, windowDuration, slideDuration)).avg()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the same as a sliding window, but it avoids keeping the data somehow...

Use an "exponential moving average":

```
avg += fact * (xn - avg)
```

Where

- `avg` is the current average; this is the only variable that need be held from one row to the next.  (As opposed to the last N values)
- `fact` is a constant fraction that controls the smoothness of the averaging --  0.01 is very slow to respond to changes; 0.5 responds quite rapidly.
- `xn` us the value (in the current row) being averaged.

Comment: can this be implemented without using a window approach?